# Pass Click Handler to Child - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass an onClick event from my parent react component down to the child but I tried a few different ways but all of them results into "null" parameters.

```
 // parent
 removeImage(event, item, params){

     console.log('deleted', item, params)
     event.stopPropagation();
   }


 render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const params = props.match.params;
    const item = props.item;
    const images = props.images;
    var i = images.map(image => {
      return <ImageComponent remove={(e) => this.removeImage(e, item, params)}/>
  })


    return (
     <div>
        {i}
    </div>
    );

// child 
  internalRemove = event => {
    this.props.remove(event);
  }
    <i className="fas fa-trash remove" onClick={this.internalRemove} />
```

Comment: the problem may be with "this", can you rewrite removeImage with arrow operator ?

Comment: I think I tried to use the arrow function but maybe I wrote it wrong. How should it look int his case?

Comment: 'removeImage' needs to be bound or an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what would make more sense is to actually pass the `item` and `params` as props to the `ImageComponent`. And then use those props via the child.

```
 // parent
 removeImage(event, item, params){

     console.log('deleted', item, params)
     event.stopPropagation();
   }


 render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const params = props.match.params;
    const item = props.item;
    const images = props.images;
    var i = images.map(image => {
      return <ImageComponent remove={this.removeImage} params={params} item={item}/>
  })


// child 
  internalRemove = event => {
    this.props.remove(event, this.props.item, this.props.params);
  }
    <i className="fas fa-trash remove" onClick={this.internalRemove} />
```

Assuming the child is a class-component, that should work.

Comment: I would do this but the idea behind trying to pass the event handler down is so I can swap it out with a different handler. The html markup is same but the removeHandler is different for different image types(mostly it is the ajax request is different).

Comment: Couldn't you just have a single removeHandler and optimize the logic inside depending on the image type by using a switch-case? @chobo2

Comment: Yeah I was mulling it over before trying this way, I thought maybe trying to pass in a customer handler would be better and cleaner as for instance I won't need "params" parameter so I will have to a check to see if it is needed or not. Which is ok but I am concerned that by the time I am done I will have so many checks because maybe not every parameters is used in any case.

Comment: I think passing in an anonymous function as a prop is creating some scoping issues. Particularly, at what point is `this.removeImage` actually getting called and at that point are params and item even available. Passing in a typical event-handler would mitigate this. I think your checks will be more robust than expected. Its essentially the same as having a different event-handler for each image-type.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to pass `remove` props directly to child onClick event:

```js
class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={this.props.remove}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
 removeItem (event, someValue) {   
  console.log('deleted', someValue)
  console.log(event.target)  
 }
 render() {
 const {props} = this
 const test = props.customProps
  var i = [1,2].map(image => {
   return <ImageComponent remove={(e) => this.removeItem(e, test)}/>
  })   
  return (
   <div>
    {i}
   </div>
  );
 }
}

class GrandParent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Parent customProps={'test'} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GrandParent />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='react'></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not following. I see in child you have this.remove. Do you mean props.remove?

Comment: @chobo2 sry, my mistake i mean `this.props.remove`

Comment: this does not seem to work as well. It does not seem to even really run.

Comment: @chobo2 I've updated my answer with snippet, take a look.